# How do I print gameserver data to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hi guys,
CSGO server's server name, number of players, online player name and scores, protocol number, etc. how do i print things to json?**

Comment: Show in what format you have these items

Comment: example: http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.7/27015

Comment: well, you already get a response from this URL in JSON format

Comment: Sometimes there are problems in the url, the timeout is thrown so I want to shoot it myself.

Comment: Please clarify in your question where and in what format do you have input data